# Remove encode64 header data while getting image as encode64.?

Tags: jquery

I had task to convert uploaded image in encode64 then send it to API I have been successful with all parts of it but i have to remove header from encode64 data.  `data:image/png;base64,`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<metea charset="utf8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#falseinput').attr('src', e.target.result);
                $('#base').val(e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>File Upload</h1>
<input id="fileinput" type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" onchange="readURL(this);" /> <br><br>
<textarea id="base"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by header in your example?

Comment: I haved edited my question i want to remove data:image/png;base64, from image encode64 and save it in textarea of my html without data:image//png;base64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to get all the text after "base64,", and then use that as your data:

```
/base64,(.+)/.exec(e.target.result)[1]
```

See example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('#falseinput').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('#base').val(/base64,(.+)/.exec(e.target.result)[1]);
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
      }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>File Upload</h1>
  <input id="fileinput" type="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" onchange="readURL(this);" /> <br><br>
  <textarea id="base"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, can you make just final change  to get file name also and what if i upload multiple images and all images get encode in seperate text boxes. without making alot of functions.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the replace function and to remove it

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#falseinput').attr('src', e.target.result);

                var base64Image = e.target.result;
                base64Image = base64Image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '')
                                            .replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '')
                                            .replace('data:image/gif;base64,', '');

                $('#base').val(base64Image);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

please put this in your script before store in textarea
`var data=e.target.result;
$('#base').val(data.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", ""));`

full script is

```
 function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#falseinput').attr('src', e.target.result);
                var data=e.target.result;
                $('#base').val(data.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", ""));
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: and what happens if I input a `png`?

Comment: you have to add other replace line in code or use abject array for replace in once

Comment: also @NickParsons use `$('#base').val(/base64,(.+)/.exec(e.target.result)[1]);`